# SharepointFoundation Workflow Body Not Comming Properly

Tags: workflow

hi here i am explaining my problem i have a SharePoint farm now i want to send an auto email to the help desk people when a user request for service for that i have created a list and a list workflow. before to this i have done all pre-configurations  like  incomming  email and out going email all then.here i am attacjhing images

i want to receive mail like below:-

[image]

but i am recieving like below:-

[image]

workflow i have created:-

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a table and referenced content to the table, if you want to have the look you're after. All of this can be done in SharePoint Designer and is a quite straight forward process.

Comment: yes i have created the workflow by using sharepoint designer only but i am not able to recieve the mail body part any configurations i need to do. And One More thing i tried TO create an alert a mail for AN item there also same mail recieving but body part not recieving

Comment: Strange. It must be some kind of configuration error, but I haven\t heard of this one before...